# Match elements that have multiple possible places in a string with a regex

Tags: regex

I'm currently working on a dice roller that accepts expressions in order to process the roll demanded by the user.

The expressions CAN take this form (at its longest) : `2d8(*2)(+20)[reroll=1]`. 
What I want to make is a regex that would check if the expression is well-structured or not, which I already made:

```
/^(\d+d\d+(\([\*]\d+\))?(\([\+]\d+\))?(\[reroll(>|=|<)\d+\])?[\+$]){1,}/
```

The problem is, I would like to have that regex ALSO match an expression that would have the parenthesis/brackets parts mixed.
Here are the expressions I would like the regex to match, while keeping every part of the expression facultative (except for the 2d8 part).

```
2d8(+20)(*2)[reroll=1]
2d8(*2)(+20)[reroll=1]
2d8(+20)[reroll=1](*2)
2d8(*2)[reroll=1](+20)
```

Is there a way to do what I want without making a very long regex that repeats itself too much.

Thank you for answers.

Comment: You mean the order in which they appear can be different, except for 2d8 which is always the start?

Answer (score 2):

As the syntax of a roll is fairly complex, why not write a parser instead of using a huge regular expression?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm sure writing a parser might be a better idea after all.